# Loop com opções

Tags: java

Como faço para criar um *loop* com opções em Java? Por exemplo: "digite 1 para salvar e 2 para excluir". E ao fazer os comandos de cada opção, voltar para o : "digite 1 para salvar e 2 para excluir".

```
import java.io.*;

public class CadastroPessoa{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
//burocracia para leitura de teclado
InputStream entradaSistema = System.in;
InputStreamReader leitor = new InputStreamReader(entradaSistema);
BufferedReader leitorEntrada = new BufferedReader(leitor);
String entradaTeclado;

//instanciando objetos do sistema
ControlePessoa umControle = new ControlePessoa();


System.out.println("Digite 1 para adicionar pessoa. Digite 2 para remover pessoa. Digite 3 para pesquisar uma pessoa. Digite 4 para sair.");
entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
String Opcao = entradaTeclado;

    String opcao1 = "1";
    String opcao2 = "2";
    String opcao3 = "3";
String opcao4 = "4"; 

while (!Opcao.equals(opcao4)){

    if (Opcao.equals(opcao1)){

        //interagindo com usuário
        System.out.println("Digite o nome da Pessoa:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umNome = entradaTeclado;

        System.out.println("Digite o telefone da Pessoa:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umTelefone = entradaTeclado;


        //adicionando uma pessoa na lista de pessoas do sistema
        Pessoa umaPessoa = new Pessoa(umNome, umTelefone);
        String mensagem = umControle.adicionar(umaPessoa);
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        }

    if (Opcao.equals(opcao2)){

        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer remover:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umNome = entradaTeclado;

        //removendo uma pessoa na lista de pessoas do sistema
        }


if (Opcao.equals(opcao3)){

        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer pesquisar:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umNome = entradaTeclado;

        //buscando pessoa na lista de pessoas


    }   
}
//conferindo saída
System.out.println("=================================");
System.out.println("=)");

}

}
```

Comment: Olá Rafael. Você já tentou alguma coisa? Tem alguma dificuldade específica? Seria bacana compartilhar na sua questão o que você já tentou fazer.

Comment: Bom, eu coloquei para ler do teclado uma string que no caso era de 1 a 4 e estava comparando essa string com strings definidas de 1 a 4. Caso fossem iguais, executaria a parte do código correspondente. Mas eu nao sei ao final disso voltar para o início para pedir que se digite uma nova string.

Comment: Essa pergunta pode parecer boba, mas o seu código de leitura está dentro de um laço (`while`, por exemplo)? Veja, você vai conseguir mais facilmente ajuda da comunidade se melhorar um pouco a sua pergunta principalmente incluindo o código que você já fez. Fica mais fácil de entender a sua dificuldade e estimula a galera a responder. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira desculpe a desorganização

Comment: Rafael, você deve editar a sua questão e colocar o código lá, não em um comentário. Aliás, coloque o código todo (no seu comentário, por exemplo, há uma variável chamada `leitorEntrada` que não está definida).

Comment: @LuizVieira agora coloquei o codigo todo na minha pergunta, obrigado desde ja pela sua ajuda e atenção.

Comment: Espero que as respostas te ajudem, mas veja que a sua questão é bem específica (isto é, uma dificuldade sua com a lógica de programação) e por isso pode receber votos negativos da comunidade. Se isso acontecer, não desanime de participar aqui. Procure apenas no futuro formular as perguntas o mais detalhadamente possível para que a comunidade seja realmente capaz de te ajudar. :)

Answer (score 3):

Bom, vamos lá. O seu código tem alguns errinhos até que comuns.

Primeiramente, na linha 25 (a condição do laço) você está usando:

```
while (Opcao != opcao4){
```

Essa condição verificará se a variável `Opcao` é diferente da variável `opcao4` em termos do seu conteúdo, ou seja, na prática se **os objetos** são diferentes. Eles sempre serão diferentes, porque você tem strings distintas. Então esse laço executará infinitamente. O ideal é corrigir para comparar o conteúdo das strings, e não os objetos em si, da seguinte forma:

```
while (!Opcao.equals(opcao4)){
```

Outro erro é que a sua variável de controle do laço se chama `Opcao` mas você não a usa para a leitura dos dados! A variável que você está usando para a leitura dos dados se chama `entradaTeclado`. Por isso, mesmo com a correção anterior o seu código ainda não funcionará corretamente. Assim, o código da linha 25 ficaria mais correto da seguinte forma:

```
while (!entradaTeclado.equals(opcao4)){
```

Independentemente desses erros, há um erro de lógica no seu laço. Você inicia o programa exibindo o seu "menu" de opções e fazendo uma leitura inicial (a opção propriamente dita). Então você entra no laço em que os dados da opção específica são solicitados. Porém, quando esse laço se encerra (e a execução retorna ao `while`), a opção não é novamente solicitada (ela está lá fora do laço, antes dele de fato). Por isso, o seu código fica eternamente solicitando os dados da primeira opção escolhida até que (devido à correção sugerida anteriormente) ele seja interrompido pela digitação do número `4` (por exemplo, faça as correções que eu sugeri acima e digite `1` na primeira vez que for solicitado; você perceberá que o código somente será encerrado se você digitar `4` no telefone da pessoa).

Devo dizer também que o seu código está um pouco desorganizado, e isso pode estar atrapalhando o seu próprio entendimento. Procure identar corretamente os níveis sempre, mesmo dentro da classe ou da função.

Outra sugestão é que você não precisa colocar os valores das opções em variáveis para a comparação, pois `if (entradaTeclado.equals("1")){` é válido. Abaixo eu proponho um código talvez mais simples que obtem o resultado que você deseja:

```
InputStream entradaSistema = System.in;
InputStreamReader leitor = new InputStreamReader(entradaSistema);
BufferedReader leitorEntrada = new BufferedReader(leitor);

String entradaTeclado;
do {
    System.out.println("Digite 1 para adicionar pessoa. Digite 2 para remover pessoa. Digite 3 para pesquisar uma pessoa. Digite 4 para sair.");
    entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();      

    if(entradaTeclado.equals("1")) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome da Pessoa:");
        String umNome = leitorEntrada.readLine();

        System.out.println("Digite o telefone da Pessoa:");
        String umTelefone = leitorEntrada.readLine();

        // Faz o que tem que fazer aqui
    }
    else if(entradaTeclado.equals("2")) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer remover:");
        String umNome = leitorEntrada.readLine();

        // Faz o que tem que fazer aqui
    }
    else if(entradaTeclado.equals("3")) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer pesquisar:");
        String umNome = leitorEntrada.readLine();

        // Faz o que tem que fazer aqui
    }
    else if(entradaTeclado.equals("4")) {
        break; // Interrompe
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Oops! Opção inválida: " + entradaTeclado);
    }       
} while(true);
```

Nesse código eu utilizei o `do...while` ao invés do `while` porque assim você pode fazer primeiro a solicitação do valor e só verificar o valor no final. Na prática eu coloquei `true` para a verificação pois a verificação do valor `4` usa o `break` para interromper. Também usei os `else if` para encadear as decisões pois assim você pode validar as opções inválidas no `else` final.

Note, entretanto, que como as suas opções são numéricas o código pode ficar mais 'simples' se você converter a entrada para um número e usar um `switch`. Note também que você não precisa ler os dados para a variável de controle `entradaTeclado`, e nem deve pois isso altera o valor da opção. Você pode ler imediatamente para as variáveis `umNome` e `umTelefone`.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer a leitura da entrada dentro da repetição, exemplo:

```
short entradaTeclado;
 do{
    //lê dado e realiza uma operação
    entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.nextShort();
    switch(entradaTeclado){
        case 1: /*faz algo*/ break;
        case 2: /*faz algo*/ break;
        case 3: /*faz algo*/ break;
    }
 }while(entradaTeclado != 4);
```

Assim, enquanto o usuário não selecionar a opção de saída, ele vai repetir o loop.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava sugerindo no final da minha resposta (mas tive preguiça de continuar). hehe :)

Comment: Gostei mais da sua resposta, mais completa e explicativa, na verdade eu que estava com preguiça e digitei apenas a solução kk. Quanto a alteração no meu código, não acho que o ultimo break seja necessário, mas não irá alterar a execuçao :)

Comment: Acho que as duas se complementam. Sobre o último `break`, você tem toda a razão. Eu só fiz porque achei que ficaria mais simples o entendimento do OP (se te incomodou, desculpe, mas pode desfazer se preferir) :)

Comment: Ligo não hehe ;)